# Retrieve a Backbone Model from a Clicked Subview and Create a New View with it

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-model

Say I've built a MainView (a list) that has populates a collection with four Backbone models. Then, for each model in the collection, I render a SubView (a list item) based off of the data in each model. Ignoring whether or not this nested view structure is optimal, how would I go about creating a click event on each subview (list item) that launches a new view referencing the model that was used to create it?

I roughed out what I'm trying to do (to some extent) in the following code:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function(){
            this.render();
    //fetch data into a collection
    this.collection.fetch().then(function(){
                this.subRender();
            });
    //view now has a list with four list items based on four models
},

events: {
    "click li": 'newView'
},

newView: function(){
    //retrieve the model from the clicked li
            //close the current view, then
    var newView = new NewView({model});
}

render: function(){
    //create an unordered list element
    this.$el.html('<ul id="list"></ul>');
},

subRender: function(){
    //for each model in the collection create a new subview
    var subView = new SubView({model: model}); // x 4 times

}

});

var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#list',

render: function(){
    //create an <li> with the passed-in model
    //append it to the list
},
});
```

EDIT: There's a post at [LosTechies](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/) that deals with this I finally found...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just have a click event, but use stopImmediatePropagation();

```
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#list',
    events: {
        "click": 'doHandler'
    },
    doHandler: function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // need this to stop other click handlers and the event bubbling up to ancestor elements
        // do stuff 
    },
    render: function(){
        //create an <li> with the passed-in model
        //append it to the list
    },
});
```

Comment: Or ditch the `"click li": 'newView'` in the parent view and let the `SubView` handle the `newView` stuff.

Comment: What I'm really driving at is how I get a reference to the clicked subview. Right now clicking any <li> in the subview and console.logging "this" (with a click event and e.stopImmediatePropagation() attached in the subview) returns the first subview, NOT the respective subview. Doing the same thing with e.stopPropagation() returns a "this" for each and every <li> (as view1, view2, view3, etc...). 

So - how would I go about return 'view2' with a click on the 2nd <li>?